# Please help me correct the syntax of the code

Tags: php

I made a code, but for some reason it does not give the necessary information. Writes a syntax problem. newbie in php. Where is the error?

```
<?php echo"<td style=\"text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:25%;background: #fff;\"><a data-fancybox="$row1['N'];" href='https://crm.armitt.ru".$row1['file']."'><img alt='".$row1['Nominaciy']." "(.$row1['Prizer'])."' src='https://crm.armitt.ru".$row1['file']."' title='".$row1['Nominaciy']." ".$row1['Prizer']."' ></a>
</td>"; 
?
```

Comment: You forgot to put `.` around `$row1['N']`

Comment: I'm not a PHP god, but I think replacing `<?php echo"<td style=\...` with `<?php echo "<td style=\...` would work. You forgot the space in between echo and the string.

Comment: `data-fancybox="$row1['N'];"` You need to escape your quotes just as you have around the style, and also put the array inside of brackets. `data-fancybox=\"{$row1['N']}\"` Or concatenate proper as the others have said, but remember that you'll probably need some sort of quotes around the value. Single quotes might be easier to read.

Comment: `fancybox="$row1['N'];"` should be `fancybox='" . $row1['N'] . "'` or `fancybox=\"{$row1['N']}\"`

Comment: Probably be easier to just use PHP where needed. `<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:25%;background: #fff;"><a data-fancybox="<?php echo $row1['N'];?>" href="https://crm.armitt.ru<?php echo $row1['file'];?>"><img alt="<?php echo $row1['Nominaciy']. ' ' .$row1['Prizer'];?> src="https://crm.armitt.ru<?php echo $row1['file'];?>" title="<?php echo $row1['Nominaciy'] . ' '. $row1['Prizer'] . '"';?>></a>
</td>`

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you. I just also wanted to use this option, but there is also a problem with it. closing" <img breaks this code. How to fix it so that it doesn't break the code

Comment: What's the rendered code?